# Commuication from aws ec2 to customer network through load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-elb

How ec2 instances behind an ELB can make a request to the customer network ? is it possible that request can go through ELB.

[image]

Comment: Can you make it more clear? I see that you already have VPNs and Customer gateway added in architecture. What is the exact issue are you facing?

Comment: if an ec2 instance makes an HTTP request  to the customer network, will it be through ELB or directly through VPN Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible for the request to go through the ELB.

How it will get to the customer network depends on your routing.  You should have a route for the subnet(s) your hosts are located in that routes traffic destined for the customer network through your VPN Gateway.

**References**

[Site to Site VPN Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/Examples.html)

[VPN Routing Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPNRoutingTypes.html)